# VBA, Changing format of tree structure

Tags: vba, excel

I have the format of a spreadsheet shown below. How would I be able to change the format of the node format to a more filterable presentation

**What I currently have, starting at Col A and each node goes over a column and row**

```
RootX
  |- Node1
       |- Node1.1
            |- Node1.1.1
                 |- Node1.1.1.1 - DataXYZ
                 |- Node1.1.1.2
                 |- Node1.1.1.3 - DataABC
       |- Node1.2
            |- Node1.2.1
                 |- Node1.2.1.1
  |- Node2
       |- Node2.1
            |- Node2.1.1
                 |- Node2.1.1.1

RootY
  |- Node3
       |- Node3.1
            |- Node3.1.1
                 |- Node3.1.1.1 - DataHIJ
            |- Node3.1.2
                 |- Node3.1.2.1
```

**Desired result:**

```
Columns   A      B      C        D          E            F
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.1  DataXYZ
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.2
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.3  DataABC
          RootX  Node1  Node1.2  Node1.2.1  Node1.2.1.1

          RootX  Node2  Node2.1  Node2.1.1  Node2.1.1.1

          RootY  Node3  Node3.1  Node3.1.1  Node3.1.1.1  DataHIJ
          RootY  Node3  Node3.1  Node3.1.2  Node3.1.2.1
```

**Edit for Bruce Wayne**

Sometimes I will have a node that should not be  filled down all the way, i.e Node1.1.1.1.1(Col H lets say)  then when that is filled down in your sample it becomes part of the rest of the  rows.  For example I wont have another node in Col H so this will just fill down all the way.  Any work arounds?

Comment: You could loop through the columns, copying the data down to the last empty cell.  Then, delete rows based on an empty cell in column D.

Comment: Or you could use temp columns (say G) with a conditional checking if Column A in the same Row has any values, if not fill in with the value above. Then you can copy as values and replaces your original table. Do the same for all levels of your tree.

Comment: In other words, there are many, many ways to implement this, and this question is *too broad*.

Comment: @BruceWayne 's solution sounds like the easiest one to me. For each end element (column F in your desired result) you would have the A -E columns as well. You then delete every line that doesn't have anything at E because the A-D will have been copied there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I'd say to provide some more info. on what you're looking for (as there are many ways to do this).  But, I have two macros that I think will do what you're looking to do without much (if any) editing.  Please note that I wrote these a long time ago (before I knew any better), so they're not very pretty.

The first one will prompt you to choose a row that has the most data (to get a lastRow), and then ask you which columns to copy the data down.  In your case, you want to copy down A, B, C, D, and E (I think E, if that has the "Node3.1.1.1 - DataHIJ" text).

```
Sub GEN_USE_Copy_Data_Down_MULTIPLE_Columns(Optional myColumns As Variant, Optional thelastRow As Variant)
Dim yearCol As Integer, countryCol As Integer, commodityCol As Integer, screenRefresh As String, runAgain As String
Dim lastRow As Long, newLastRow As Long
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim c       As Range
Dim Cell    As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim LastRowCounter As String
Dim columnArray() As String
Dim Column2Copy As String

If Not IsMissing(myColumns) Then
    columnArray() = Split(myColumns)
Else
    MsgBox ("Now, you will choose a column, and that column's data will be pasted in the range" & vbCrLf & "below the current cell, to the next full cell")
    Column2Copy = InputBox("What columns (A,B,C, etc.) would you like to copy the data of?  Use SPACES, to separate columns")
    columnArray() = Split(Column2Copy)
    screenRefresh = MsgBox("Turn OFF screen updating while macro runs?", vbYesNo)
    If screenRefresh = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If

Dim EffectiveDateCol As Integer
If IsMissing(thelastRow) Then
    LastRowCounter = InputBox("What column has the most data (this info will be used to find the last used row")
Else
    LastRowCounter = thelastRow
    lastRow = thelastRow
End If

CopyAgain:
If IsMissing(thelastRow) Then
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCounter).End(xlUp).row
        'lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End With
End If

Dim startCell As Range

For i = LBound(columnArray) To UBound(columnArray)
    Debug.Print columnArray(i) & " is going to be copied now."
    Column2Copy = columnArray(i)

    Set startCell = Cells(1, Column2Copy).End(xlDown)
    Do While startCell.row < lastRow
        If startCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row > lastRow Then
            newLastRow = lastRow
        Else
            newLastRow = startCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row
        End If
        Set copyFrom = startCell
        Range(Cells(startCell.row, Column2Copy), Cells(newLastRow, Column2Copy)).Value = copyFrom.Value
        Set startCell = startCell.End(xlDown)
    Loop
Next i

If IsEmpty(myColumns) Then
runAgain = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on another column?", vbYesNo)
If runAgain = vbNo Then
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Exit Sub
ElseIf runAgain = vbYes Then
    GoTo CopyAgain
End If
End If

MsgBox ("Done!")


End Sub
```

Then, run this one, and choose a row that you want to delete, when a blank cell is found. I think you should be able to use column D (or maybe it's E?).

```
Sub GEN_USE_Delete_Entire_Row_based_on_Empty_Cell(Optional thelastRow As Variant, Optional iColumn As Variant)
Dim yearCol As Integer, countryCol As Integer, commodityCol As Integer, screenRefresh As String
Dim lastRow As Long, newLastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim c       As Range
Dim Cell    As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim LastRowCounter As String
Dim i       As Long

Dim aRng As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range

If IsMissing(thelastRow) Then
    screenRefresh = MsgBox("Turn OFF screen updating while macro runs?", vbYesNo)
    If screenRefresh = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If

Dim EffectiveDateCol As Integer
If IsMissing(thelastRow) Then
    LastRowCounter = InputBox("What column has the most data (this info will be used to find the last used row)")
Else
    LastRowCounter = iColumn
End If
'Note, you can use LastRow2 to also find the last row, without prompting the user...but note it uses ACTIVECELL
LastRow2 = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

CopyAgain:
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCounter).End(xlUp).row
End With


If IsMissing(iColumn) Then
MsgBox ("Now, you will choose a column.  Any cell in that column that is blank, will have that ENTIRE ROW deleted")
End If
Dim Column2DeleteRowsFrom As String

If IsMissing(iColumn) Then
Column2DeleteRowsFrom = InputBox("What column (A,B,C, etc.) would you like to delete entire row when a blank cell is found?")
Else
    Column2DeleteRowsFrom = iColumn
End If
'If there are headers, then stop deleting at row 2
Dim headerQ As Integer
If IsMissing(iColumn) Then
headerQ = MsgBox("Does the sheet have headers?", vbYesNo)
If headerQ = vbYes Then
    headerQ = 2
Else
    headerQ = 1
End If
Else
    headerQ = 2
End If

Set cell1 = Cells(2, Column2DeleteRowsFrom)
Set cell2 = Cells(lastRow, Column2DeleteRowsFrom)
Set aRng = Range(cell1, cell2)

Range(Cells(headerQ, Column2DeleteRowsFrom), Cells(lastRow, Column2DeleteRowsFrom)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

MsgBox ("Done removing blank cell rows!")

End Sub
```

Yeahhh, so as I said, they're not very pretty.  I leave it as an exercise for the reader to tighten up/remove superfluous stuff.

Comment: Wow this works really good. However I have a stipulation, can you check updated question?

Comment: Sometimes I will have a node that should not be filled down all the way, i.e Node1.1.1.1.1(Col H lets say) then when that is filled down in your sample it becomes part of the rest of the rows. For example I wont have another node in Col H so this will just fill down all the way. Any work arounds?

Comment: when filling down in a Col it should almost stop the fill down when the  column to the left of it  changes field names.